# getting started (not) with Heroku: App not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

This should be simple, and I *swear* it was working an hour ago.  I can log in to Heroku, but can't run any useful commands:

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: xxx@whatever.com
Password: 
$ heroku stack
App not found
$ heroku config
App not found
```

Perhaps this is the source of the problem?

```
$ git remote show heroku
!  No such app as empty-samurai-345
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

empty-samuri-345 was an app I deleted earlier.  All I really want to do is upload a new app using the bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack.

Thanks in advance for suggestions...

Comment: I had similar symptoms, and it turned out the problem was I was logged into a different Heroku account.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to remove the heroku remote in `git` using this command:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Then you can add a new remote using this one:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:your-app.git
```

Then try running your `heroku` commands.

Comment: Nifty -- thanks.  I ended up editing the .git file to remove the heroku entry -- that also seemed to work.

Comment: This is documented here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps#updating-git-remotes

Comment: I was having the same problem because I renamed my app. I opened `.git/config` and change the Heroku repo URL and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Run the following

```
git config -l
```

The config key is easy to spot, `remote.heroku.url`.

Now if your comfortable editing the config directly, just:

```
git config -e
```

If not:

```
# Confirm you've got the right key
git config remote.heroku.url
# Substitute your_app_name appropriately
git config remote.heroku.url git@heroku.com:your_app_name.git
```

My answer is based off fearless_fool's comment, which lacks much detail.

FYI: The config file is located in /your_git_repo/.git/config

Comment: After editing the file, escape to leave insert mode and :wq to save and exit.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same problem by renaming my app from heroku online dashboard.
Then I tried running some command in cli from my local machine and it gave 'App not found'. I guess Cli doesn't know the change that I renamed my app.

So I again logged into heroku website and renamed the app with old name.
Then All commands worked from cli.

**So Don't use online dashboard to rename your app, use CLI.**

I hope it helps someone..!!

Comment: Rather than using the dashboard to undo the name change, you should instead edit your repo's `.git/config` (the shortcut do doing that is `git config -e`) and replace the old name with the new name (i.e. change `url = git@heroku.com:old-name-1234.git` to `url = git@heroku.com:new-name-5678.git`). See the answer by @derek-litz http://stackoverflow.com/a/11739726/664833