# renamed heroku app from website, now it's not found

Tags: git, heroku

After renaming my heroku app from the heroku website, whenever I cd to its directory in a terminal and run any heroku command, I get `App not found`. Does anybody know of a way to remedy this?

Comment: might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383670/how-to-change-a-ruby-on-rails-application-name

Comment: thanks, @Hishalv. i think that thread has to deal more with Rails apps being renamed, not necessarily from heroku though. i'm looking for some help that's specific to renaming an app on heroku.

Comment: This may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305843/getting-started-not-with-heroku-app-not-found

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Try to update the git remote for the app:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:yourappname.git
```

Comment: can rename apps from cli: `$ heroku apps:rename newname` docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps

Comment: @ConnorLeech allegedly yes, but actually that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JohnLaBarge Yup, I just arrived at this answer because a rename from the CLI left me with "app not found" when I tried to do anything afterwards.

Answer (score 47):

The Answer by James Ward is also correct, alternatively try doing this:

1). open a terminal

2). Go to your_app_directory/.git/config

3). Once you open the config file then edit as follows:

Change

```
url = git@heroku.com:old_app_name.git
```

to

```
url = git@heroku.com:new_app_name.git
```

Obviously substituting your apps old name to its new name. Hope it helps
Also checkout this link [renaming from cli - heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps)

Comment: +1 Yeah, James' answer is correct, but for some reason I liked yours better. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for renaming link and finding the command `heroku apps:rename newname`

Answer (score 22):

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a newname
```

Answer (score 6):

From [the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps#updating-git-remotes)...

> If you rename from the website ... [your app] will need to be updated manually:

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a newname
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another way, you can fix it by renaming the app to the original name via web.

To find out the old name use heroku command line:

```
> heroku rename newname
```

which will spit out the old name. Use the old name to rename the app via web.  You can check if renaming success by running

```
> heroku info
```

Once done you can rename to the preferred name by using

```
> heroku rename preferredname
```

Answer (score 3):

James Ward's solution didn't work for me. I had to enter my git url in a different format:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/appname.git
```