# Git push failing after Heroku app name change

Tags: git, heroku

I changed my app name from "my-app-staging" to "my-app-staging-new" in the Heroku dashboard. Now I can no longer push changes to it- git throws the following error:

> !  No such app as my-app-staging.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

How do I resolve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [renamed heroku app from website, now it's not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615807/renamed-heroku-app-from-website-now-its-not-found)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to change your git remote.

If you do `git remote -v` you should see `heroku` listed.

It will look something like:

`heroku  git@github.com:my-app-staging.git (fetch)`
`heroku  git@github.com:my-app-staging.git (push)`

Delete that remote...

`git remote rm heroku`

...and then add the new one

`git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:my-app-staging-new.git`

Comment: for me the last command work with:  git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git

Answer (score 2):

First Delete the Old remote

$ git remote rm heroku

Then Add the New One:

$ heroku git:remote -a ***newname***

Answer (score 0):

First

```
git remote rm heroku
```

to remove the old remote. Then

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:new-app-name.git
```

to add the new remote. Finally

```
heroku keys:add
```

to set a public ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

Note that now you need to specify your heroku app name in a slightly different format:

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/your-app-name.git
```

You can see it in your heroku dashboard settings at: Heroku git URL