# Missing steps in heroku app renaming

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am on the heroku documentation.  I am pushing my node app to heroku and it was working fine but I need to change the website name.   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps

It shows me that I can rename my app very simply

```
 heroku apps:rename newname
```

Step 2: I just change it on git and I was good to go on the heroku site.

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a newname
```

I did the next steps for git and received

```
 !    `git:` is not a heroku command.
```

a app not found when I tried to push to the the heroku master.  Is there another step that I am missing?

Comment: Check this out for renaming you heroku app.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941015/git-push-failing-after-heroku-app-name-change

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an older version of the heroku client installed. What do you get when you run `heroku version`? The `heroku git:remote -a` command works with the latest version:

```
$ heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/3.37.2 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3                                                                                                                                                                                                    
heroku-cli/4.19.28-8f2bd89 (amd64-darwin) go1.4.2
```

If you are seeing an older version run `heroku update` and try again.