# Renamed Heroku's hostname, now it can't find the application

Tags: django, heroku, cloud

I previously had my Heroku's application name at:

shielded-meadow-9293.heroku.com

This was the name when I created the Heroku remote and fired up the dyno. After everything was running smooth, I changed the name to

platformdesignmadness.heroku.com

The site works, but in the same terminal, when I do a command such as

`heroku ps`

I get a `$>  !    Couldn't find that app.` error. Why is this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In your terminal:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:yourappname.git
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615807/renamed-heroku-app-from-website-now-its-not-found)

Heroku docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps#updating-git-remotes).

Answer (score 1):

For all the people showing up here trying to figure out why a

```
$ heroku run:detached python script.py -n yyy -a zzzz
```

command isn't working, and giving this error:

```
▸    Couldn't find that app.
```

it's because Heroku senses the `-a` argument as the app name. To ignore these the fix is [this](https://github.com/heroku/legacy-cli/issues/1264), basically adding a `--`:

```
$ heroku run:detached -- python script.py -n yyy -a zzzz
```

and now it will work properly.