# Heroku and Django : error "Couldn't find that app" from terminal/CLI

Tags: django, heroku

I am employing my Django website into Heroku.

I followed:

a) `heroku login`

b) `heroku create`

Which produces:

```
Creating app... done, ⬢ enigmatic-ridge-36610
https://enigmatic-ridge-36610.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-ridge-36610.git
```

c) `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

Which produces:

> > Creating heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev on ⬢ morning-gorge-61422... !
> >      ▸    Couldn't find that app.

I tried this guide: ["Couldn't find that app." when running heroku commands in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551717/couldnt-find-that-app-when-running-heroku-commands-in-console)

But it did not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the following:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:yourappname.git
```

where `yourappname` is your heroku app name, not your Django project name

[Renamed Heroku's hostname, now it can't find the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160131/renamed-herokus-hostname-now-it-cant-find-the-application)